# Kotlin - TypeReference<T> Cannot obtain Class<*> For Type Arguments

Tags: kotlin

I've created a Kotlin equivalent of `TypeReference<T>` like so:

```kotlin
abstract class TypeReference<T> : Comparable<T> {

    val type: Type get() = getGenericType()
    val arguments: List<Type> get() = getTypeArguments()

    final override fun compareTo(other: T): Int {
        return 0
    }

    private fun getGenericType(): Type {
        val superClass = javaClass.genericSuperclass

        check(superClass !is Class<*>) {
            "TypeReference constructed without actual type information."
        }

        return (superClass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]
    }

    private fun getTypeArguments(): List<Type> {
        val type = getGenericType()
        return if (type is ParameterizedType) {
            type.actualTypeArguments.toList()
        } else emptyList()
    }
}
```

In order to obtain `Class<*>` of the generic type and its arguments, I've also created the following extension function (and this is where I believe the problem lies, since this is where the stack trace fails).

```kotlin
fun Type.toClass(): Class<*> = when (this) {
    is ParameterizedType -> rawType.toClass()
    is Class<*> -> this
    else -> Class.forName(typeName)
}
```

I'm unit testing this like so:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `TypeReference should correctly identify the List of BigDecimal type`() {

    // Arrange
    val expected = List::class.java
    val expectedParameter1 = BigDecimal::class.java
    val typeReference = object : TypeReference<List<BigDecimal>>() {}

    // Act
    val actual = typeReference.type.toClass()
    val actualParameter1 = typeReference.arguments[0].toClass()

    // Assert
    assertEquals(expected, actual)
    assertEquals(expectedParameter1, actualParameter1)
}
```

The problem I think, lies in the extension function `else -> Class.forName(typeName)` as it throws:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ? extends java.math.BigDecimal

Is there a better way to obtain the `Class<*>` of a `Type`, even when they're generic type parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `is WildcardType -> ...` branch to your `when`-expression to handle types like `? extends java.math.BigDecimal` (Kotlin equivalent is `out java.math.BigDecimal`), `?`(Kotlin equivalent is `*`), `? super Integer`(Kotlin equivalent is `in java.math.Integer`):

```kotlin
fun Type.toClass(): Class<*> = when (this) {
    is ParameterizedType -> rawType.toClass()
    is Class<*> -> this
    is WildcardType -> upperBounds.singleOrNull()?.toClass() ?: Any::class.java
    else -> Class.forName(typeName)
}
```

Note that in this implementation single upper bound types will be resolved as its upper bound, but all other [wildcard types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) (including multiple upper bounds types) will be resolved as `Class<Object>`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I actually solved it just like this, although I suspect that there’s a more elegant way to cast Type to Class.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/pluses/ktypes

```
val typeReference = object : TypeReference<List<BigDecimal>>() {}

val superType = typeReference::class.createType().findSuperType(TypeReference::class)!!

println(superType.arguments.first())// List<java.math.BigDecimal>
println(superType.arguments.first().type?.arguments?.first())// java.math.BigDecimal
```