# Kotlin: Getting actual generic type of super interface via reflection

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection, parent, super

```
open class Device

class Router : Device()

interface GenericDAO<T, ID>

open class DeviceDAO<T : Device> : GenericDAO<T, Long>

class RouterDAO : DeviceDAO<Router>()
```

I need a function get T and ID actual type

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66505467/kotlin-typereferencet-cannot-obtain-class-for-type-arguments/

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/pluses/ktypes

```
val genericDAOType = RouterDAO::class.starProjectedType.findSuperType(GenericDAO::class)!!

println(genericDAOType.arguments.first())// Router

println(genericDAOType.arguments[2])// Long
```